# Send grid Event API is not posting data as request parameters

Tags: jsp, email, sendgrid

I am using send-grid for sending mails from my application. I am using its Event Notification App for tracking bounced emails. The URL i have configured redirects to a JSP where i fetched my custom parameters. These custom parameters i set while sending mail in SMTP mail header. 
This JSP fetch custom parameters like:

```
String customParam = request.getParameter("X-customParam");
```

This code was working till mid august but stopped working now. The variable customParam is now initialized to NULL.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Disclosure: I'm a SendGrid employee.

I've never seen X-customParam anywhere on our end. I presume you're using our "unique_args" setup?

If so, here's a link to our documentation on how to fetch that data from the POST we make to your endpoint.

http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html#-Unique-Arguments-and-Categories